# How to move /home to a new partition fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, filesystems, partition

I am new on linux, I have windows 10 and Fedora dual booted on my laptop. I finished the space in the /home folder and I am trying to resolve this problem. I allocated a free space on my disk to fedora using this guide: [Increase Linux partition with unused Windows partition space on dualbooot system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444148/increase-linux-partition-with-unused-windows-partition-space-on-dualbooot-system). But now I would like to move my /home partition to the new space. It's possible? How can I do it?
usefull information are:

Output of lsblk command:
[image]
and the output of df -lh and parted -l commands
[image]
pvs output:

```
 PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sda6  fedora lvm2 a--  <50,33g      0 
  /dev/sda7  fedora lvm2 a--  <30,00g <30,00g
```

Comment: It's sooo much easier for us to read what comes from a terminal if you copy it all then paste it into the question, instead of taking pictures. However, of all the screenshot pictures I have seen this year, yours are undoubtedly the clearest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've followed the guide you linked *exactly*, then `/dev/sda7` should be your new free space.

Since Fedora is using LVM, this is going to be easy. You don't actually *have to* move your `/home` filesystem (i.e. the `/dev/mapper/fedora-home` logical volume to `/dev/sda7` to extend it: as soon as you add `/dev/sda7` to the `fedora` Volume Group, you can extend *any* of the logical volumes (LVs for short) inside it.

First, boot into your regular Fedora and become root.
(Yes, all the remaining steps can be done in regular Fedora, without GParted Live or similar!)

To make `/dev/sda7` useful for LVM, you'll first need to use `pvcreate` on it. This will effectively destroy any existing data on the partition it's aimed at, so be careful.

```
pvcreate /dev/sda7
```

This makes `/dev/sda7` into a new LVM Physical Volume, or PV for short.
The next step is to add it into your `fedora` volume group (VG):

```
vgextend fedora /dev/sda7
```

At this point, you can use the `pvs` and `vgs` commands to confirm that `/dev/sda7` now registers as a LVM PV that is a member of `fedora` VG. You'll also see that the VG will have some unallocated space available.

Now, if you really want to *move* your `/home` filesystem to `/dev/sda7`, you can do it with the following command:

```
pvmove -n home /dev/sda6 /dev/sda7
```

Yes, you can do this while `/home` is still mounted and in use!

But if you don't have any strange special requirement that your `/home` filesystem must be physically contiguous, *you don't have to do that*.

As long as you have unallocated space in your VG, you can extend *any* of the LVs inside that VG. LVM will present the space allocated to the LV as a single logically contiguous unit to the filesystem driver, even if the disk space is physically in separate PVs, or even on separate physical disks. You could just *extend* your /home LV by whatever amount you wish, up to the amount of unallocated space available within the VG. For example, to extend your `/home` filesystem by 32 gigabytes, you need just one more command:

```
lvextend -r -L +32G /dev/mapper/fedora-home
```

This operation can also be done on-line, while the `/home` filesystem is mounted and in use.

Just remember that while many filesystem can be extended, even on-line, it does not necessarily mean the filesystem can be shrunk as easily. In particular, the XFS filesystem type allows on-line extensions just fine, but shrinking - even off-line shrinking - may not be possible at all. (I think there are fairly recent developments in this area, but not necessarily production quality yet!)

Comment: Thank you to have been so exhaustive, no I don't need that /home have to be countiguous, but when i try to use pvcreate it says to me: "Can't initialize physical volume "/dev/sda7" of volume group "fedora" without -ff
  /dev/sda7: physical volume not initialized." So i have to add -ff? I think it's to force, maybe I am doing something wrong...

Comment: "Can't initialize.. without -ff" means pvcreate thinks the partition is already in use by something. Be very careful, don't proceed unless you're absolutely sure it's unused. Please add the output of `pvs` to your question.

Comment: Ok, I added pvs output to the question, it seems free space, but I wait for your confirmation.

Comment: `/dev/sda7` is already a member of the `fedora` VG, so effectively, the `pvcreate` and `vgextend` steps are already done. You can just proceed with `lvextend` (or `pvmove`, if you wish).

Comment: This is the output ```[root@localhost simonecastellitto]# lvextend -r -L +30G /dev/mapper/fedora-lvhome
  Logical volume lvhome not found in volume group fedora.```

Comment: Oops, sorry, the device should be `/dev/mapper/fedora-home`, not `...-lvhome`. Editing...

Comment: Ok, now all seems work fine, i am very grateful for your help.

Comment: Working on Fedora 32, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 old options;

1. fstab
2. mount --bind
3. ln -s

zfs/brtfs have other tools but you are not using them.

as you are using fstab on lvm something like

```
lvextend /dev/mapper/fedora-home
resize2fs /dev/mapper/fedora-home
```

would work but you should post output of

```
pvs;vgs;lvs;pvdispay;vgdisplay;lvdisplay
```