# Increase CentOS root partition with unused Windows partition space on dualbooot system

Tags: centos, partition, windows, dual-boot, lvm

I am using windows and centos 8 stream dual boot. I want to extend the size of the centos root . I found this link

[Increase Linux partition with unused Windows partition space on dualbooot system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444148/increase-linux-partition-with-unused-windows-partition-space-on-dualbooot-system/663290?noredirect=1#comment1247796_663290)

and followed the step mentioned in it. I shrank some memory from my windows and created a new partition using GParted. And in the rescue mode, I created the physical volume of this partition and tried to use this to extend the size of root in LVM of the centos. When I tried to run e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/cs-root or e2fsck -f /dev/cs/root, it is not running and showing the errors as shown in the figure

[image]

Due to this I could not use resize2fs command even though i can use lvextend command. How to remove this error and increase the size of the root partition successfully?

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not use `e2fsck` nor `resize2fs` here. Because in your picture, `e2fsck` says:

```
/dev/mapper/cs-root contains a xfs file system
```

`e2fsck` and `resize2fs` are for `ext2`, `ext3` and `ext4` filesystem types **only.** Trying to use the repair/extension tools of a wrong filesystem type will not work and might cause damage if forced.

If you've already used `lvextend`, the correct command to extend an XFS root filesystem is `xfs_growfs /`, or alternatively `fsadm resize /dev/mapper/cs-root`. Yes, these commands are designed to extend the filesystem while it is mounted and in use.

If you haven't yet used `lvextend`, you could have it automatically extend the filesystem too, by adding the `--resizefs` option (or `-r` for short) to your `lvextend` command line.

Comment: Ya, I used lvextend and then fsadm resize /dev/mapper/cs-root. Now the size of the root got extended successfully and its working properly.